# Sorting Boxes on a Page(2D Plane) top to bottom, left to right. (Python)

Tags: python, sorting, opencv, ocr

I am trying to sort boxes which are result of OCR engine. The bounding boxes from the engine are random and not in any particular sorting. I would like to sort the boxes from left to right, top to bottom. Which is the boxes in same row(line) should be sorted left to right, and than it should go to below row(line) and sort it left to right and so on.

I have all the 4 points of each rectangle(box)

Here are some sample Images.

[Sample Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHXNF.jpg)

[Sample Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chxFB.jpg)

[Sample Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhxmZ.jpg)

Comment: Suggestion: 1) Compute the coordinates of the center of every box; 2) Use clustering on the vertical coordinate to group the boxes per line; 3) Sort the lines, and sort the boxes on each line.

Comment: Are you able to separate overlapping boxes? Is in top-to-bottom the top or the center of the box relevant?

Comment: @Stef Yes, I thought of the same approach, but the `clustering on vertical co-ordinate` is something I am struggling to do. How to cluster on y-axis?
There are some approaches which I tried which is take top most element, and getting all points which are below the center of selected point and consider those points in the same line. Remove the selected boxes and repeat. But it doesn't seem to work well.

Comment: @SyedAbdul Have you tried using the clustering algorithms from scikit-learn? If you know the number of lines, then k-means should be perfect for this. If you don't know the number of lines, then hierarchical clustering should work pretty well. See https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html

Comment: @SyedAbdul In particular, if you know that the vertical distance between two different boxes that are not on the same line is always at least some constant (say 0.5cm) then any of the clustering algorithms from scikit-learn that accepts a `distance_threshold` parameter can work pretty well.

Comment: @SyedAbdul Alternatively, instead of using only the vertical coordinate of the centers of the boxes, you could say "two boxes are on the same line if their vertical overlap is > 50%" or something similar.

Comment: Could you please edit your question with an example of, say, a list of 16 boxes from 4 different lines, given not as an image, but as a list of coordinates?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proposition:

- Sort by vertical coordinate of the center of the box;
- Two boxes that are adjacent in the sorted list are considered "on the same line" if their vertical overlap is greater than 50% of the height of the first box.

We'll use python's [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) and [`more_itertools.split_when`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.split_when) to sort then group according to these criteria.

```py
from more_itertools import split_when

def get_y_center(b):
    up, down= b[0], b[2]
    return (up + down) / 2

def not_vertically_overlapping(b1, b2):
    up1, down1 = b1[0], b1[2]
    up2, down2 = b2[0], b2[2]
    return down1 < up2 or (down1 - up2) < (up2 - up1) 

def groupbyrow(boxes):
    sorted_boxes = sorted(boxes, key=get_y_center)
    return list(split_when(sorted_boxes, not_vertically_overlapping))
```

Testing:

```py
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors

# GENERATE RANDOM BOXES

centers = [(random.gauss(i, 5),random.gauss(j,0.25)) for i in range(0,40,10) for j in range(0,40,2)]
random.shuffle(centers)
boxes = [(y-(h:=random.gauss(1,0.25)),x-(w:=random.gauss(5,2)),y+h,x+w) for x,y in centers]

# GROUP BOXES BY ROW

rows = groupbyrow(boxes)

# DRAW BOXES WITH ONE COLOUR PER ROW

def draw_box(box, colour):
    u,l,d,r = box
    xs = [l, r, r, l, l]
    ys = [u, u, d, d, u]
    plt.plot(xs, ys, colour)

colours = list(mcolors.CSS4_COLORS.keys())

for i,row in enumerate(rows):
    for box in row:
        draw_box(box, colours[i])

plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image: Boxes coloured by row]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**sorted**](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) function, which is build-in Python function, as below (this code supposes that rects are stored as tuples of **(x, y, width, height)** or **(x1, y1, x2, y2)**:

```
from operator import itemgetter, attrgetter
rects = [(8, 10, 10, 10), (0, 5, 10, 10), (0, 0, 10, 10), (1, 10, 10, 10)]

rects = sorted(rects, key=itemgetter(1,0))
```

**Result:**

```
[(0, 0, 10, 10), (0, 5, 10, 10), (1, 10, 10, 10), (8, 10, 10, 10)]
```

Comment: The boxes are not in straight line, like the example you took is all y-axis are in straight line and the boxes are of same size. But in my case the boxes are all of different sizes and the center point of boxes are also not in straight line. So the direct sorted function won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please summarize the rules you are considering to sort the boxes? Do you want to sort boxes in Zigzag order scanning? Anyway, if you want to apply a specific rule, you can pass your customized **Comparator** function to sorted function.